# Highest value of one row of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, row, multidimensional-array

I have a problem finding out the highest value of one row of a multidimensional array.

The array is like:

```
$array[$days][events]
```

I am looping from 1 to 31 (the days of a month) to receive the number of events on the day $days.

For the next step I need to know the highest index (value) of the *events* row. (Can be any number from 0 to 1293xxxx)

I have already tried count, but it just returns the number of events, not the last event index.

Answer (score 0):

First make an array which contain each day's higher value with `max()`, then use `max()` on this new array and you're ok

```
$cnt = 0;
$tab = array();
while (isset($array[$cnt]))
{
    $tab[] = max($array[$cnt]);
    cnt++;
}
$maxvalue = max($tab);
```

EDIT: sorry i didn't understand, what i wrote will take the global hightest.

You just need to use `max()` on the table you want. Good luck

Comment: `max() [function.max]: When only one parameter is given, it must be an array in .../calendar.inc.php on line 382`

when I use $maxi = max($array[$days][events]);

Comment: Use  $maxi = max($array[$days])

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; $i++) {
  ksort($array[$i], SORT_NUMERIC);
  end($array[$i]);
  $events[$i] = key($events);
}
```